# How tosolve the Devc++ can't find afxwin.h file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have already use visual c++6.0 to open a projecct,but it always stop working.Then I use Devc++ to open it,but it tell me that `15 64  E:\vc++6.0\TestPilot_E20A\stdafx.h  [Error] afxwin.h: No such file or directory` 
So how to solve it?Thank you!

Comment: That header is part of MFC library which is not bundled with DevC++